# Getting Vega-Lite / D3 to Work in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, nuxt.js, vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to get a simple Vega-Lite visualization to work in Nuxt and struggling. Here's Vega-Lite's [documentation on how to embed](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/usage/embed.html) a simple chart into an HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Embedding Vega-Lite</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.10.1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.10.2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.5.2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vis"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var yourVlSpec = {
        $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.0.json',
        description: 'A simple bar chart with embedded data.',
        data: {
          values: [
            {a: 'A', b: 28},
            {a: 'B', b: 55},
            {a: 'C', b: 43},
            {a: 'D', b: 91},
            {a: 'E', b: 81},
            {a: 'F', b: 53},
            {a: 'G', b: 19},
            {a: 'H', b: 87},
            {a: 'I', b: 52}
          ]
        },
        mark: 'bar',
        encoding: {
          x: {field: 'a', type: 'ordinal'},
          y: {field: 'b', type: 'quantitative'}
        }
      };
      vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would I get that syntax to work in Nuxt?

I tried this:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div id="vis"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import vegaEmbed from 'vega-embed'

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      chart1: {
              $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.0.json',
        description: 'A simple bar chart with embedded data.',
        data: {
          values: [
            {a: 'A', b: 28},
            {a: 'B', b: 55},
            {a: 'C', b: 43},
            {a: 'D', b: 91},
            {a: 'E', b: 81},
            {a: 'F', b: 53},
            {a: 'G', b: 19},
            {a: 'H', b: 87},
            {a: 'I', b: 52}
          ]
        },
        mark: 'bar',
        encoding: {
          x: {field: 'a', type: 'ordinal'},
          y: {field: 'b', type: 'quantitative'}
        }
      }
    }
    },

    methods: {
      async draw(){

        let yourV1Spec = JSON.parse(this.chart1)
        await vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
      }      
    },
}

</script>
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong because it doesn't work. At least I know the data part is working right, though. It's the vegaEmbed part that I can't figure out.

Thus far, the only way I can get this to work properly is if I do the Vega visualization in a separate .js file and import it in my .vue file.

```
import vegaEmbed from 'vega-embed';

var yourV1Spec = {

{
        $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.0.json',
        description: 'A simple bar chart with embedded data.',
        data: {
          values: [
            {a: 'A', b: 28},
            {a: 'B', b: 55},
            {a: 'C', b: 43},
            {a: 'D', b: 91},
            {a: 'E', b: 81},
            {a: 'F', b: 53},
            {a: 'G', b: 19},
            {a: 'H', b: 87},
            {a: 'I', b: 52}
          ]
        },
        mark: 'bar',
        encoding: {
          x: {field: 'a', type: 'ordinal'},
          y: {field: 'b', type: 'quantitative'}
        }
      };


    // Embed the visualization in the container with id `vis`
    vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
```

But how would I do this in a more proper Vue / Nuxt type style and get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

In your failing example, you are passing a JavaScript object (`this.chart1`) into `JSON.parse`, which expects a string. Did you see any hints in the javascript error console?

Perhaps it would work if you simply called `await vegaEmbed('#vis', this.chart1);`

Additionally, it doesn't look like your `draw` method gets called anywhere. You may want to put that code inside of something like the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) life-cycle hook, so that the vega-embed code runs once the component has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

**It works like this in Nuxt with SSR set to false.**

```
<template>
    <div id="vis"></div>
</template>

<script>
import embed from 'vega-embed'

export default {
    name: 'BarChart',
    mounted() {
        this.draw()
    },
    data() {
        return {
            chart1: {
                $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
                description: 'A simple bar chart with embedded data.',
                data: {
                    values: [
                        { a: 'A', b: 28 },
                        { a: 'B', b: 55 },
                        { a: 'C', b: 43 },
                        { a: 'D', b: 91 },
                        { a: 'E', b: 81 },
                        { a: 'F', b: 53 },
                        { a: 'G', b: 19 },
                        { a: 'H', b: 87 },
                        { a: 'I', b: 52 },
                    ],
                },
                mark: 'bar',
                encoding: {
                    x: { field: 'a', type: 'nominal', axis: { labelAngle: 0 } },
                    y: { field: 'b', type: 'quantitative' },
                },
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async draw() {
            const result = await embed('#vis', this.chart1)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

**Yet, when SSR is set to true, it returns:**

```
SyntaxError
Unexpected token '??='
```